# Print optimal days for stock purchase transactions

Tags: python, stock

Please help me understand the algorithm I need to use to find a set of 4 or fewer pairs of "purchase and sale" transactions to get the maximum benefit.

I couldn't figure out how to write the algorithm myself. The best I came up with is to cut the list of prices on different days into sublists so that the beginning of the next sublist is less than the end of the previous one, that is, split into consecutive sublists.

Here's the problem statement:

> For simplicity of calculations, it is possible to buy and sell any fractional part of the stock. For example, if a stock costs $2 and you have $3 available, then you can buy 1.5 shares.

> The teacher expects Jack to calculate the largest amount of money that can be obtained from 1 dollar at the start, having made no more than four transactions.
>
> Input:
> N - number of days
> N numbers - price of 1 stock every day

> Output:
> Number of transactions
> Pairs of two digits - the days of purchase and sell (1 - indexed)

The problem also came with a few test cases below.

Test Case 1.

> Input:
> 6
> 1 4 2 3 3 5
>
> Expected Output:
> 2
> 1 2
> 3 6

Test Case 2.

> Input:
> 5
> 10 5 5 7 6
>
> Expected Output:
> 1
> 3 4

Test Case 3.

> Input:
> 3
> 3 2 2
>
> Expected Output:
> 0

This is the code I tried:

```py
N = int(input())
prices = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
dprices = dict(zip(range(1, N + 1), prices))
a = []
s = []
i = prices.index(min(prices))
while i != len(prices) - 1:
    s.append(prices[i])
    if prices[i] > prices[i+1] or i == len(prices)-2:
        a.append(s)
        s = []
    i += 1
a[-1].append(prices[-1])
print(a)
day1 = []
day2 = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for key, value in dprices.items():
        if a[i][0] == value:
            day1.append(key)
        if a[i][-1] == value:
            day2.append(key)

days = tuple(zip(day1, day2))
print(len(days))
for item in days:
    print(*item)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most straightforward (though maybe not most intuitive) ways to solve this problem is by using a recursive algorithm. For each possible buy and sell day, we calculate the amount of profit we could make by buying and selling on those days, then run the algorithm again on the remaining days and calculate the total profit. We keep track of the largest profit found, then return that at the end:

```py
# Process input
N = int(input())
prices = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

# Day is what day to start searching on, and curTransactions is the number of
# transactions that have already been used up
def solve(day, curTransactions):
    # If we've run out of days or used up all our transactions, it's impossible
    # to make any more profit.
    if day >= N or curTransactions == 4:
        return 1, []
    
    maxProfit = 1
    bestTransactions = []
    
    # Iterate through all available buy and sell days
    for buyDay in range(day, N):
        for sellDay in range(buyDay + 1, N):

            # If the price of the sell day is the same or higher than the
            # buy day, skip it - we can't make profit from that
            if prices[buyDay] >= prices[sellDay]:
                continue
            
            # We can sell higher than we bought. Calculate the max profit we
            # can earn with our remaining transactions after this sell day.
            profit, transactions = solve(sellDay + 1, curTransactions + 1)

            # Multiply the profit we can make after this transaction by the
            # amount we earned from this transaction (gains compound)
            profit *= prices[sellDay] / prices[buyDay]

            # If this is the most profitable transaction we've calculated, or
            # we made the same amount of profit in fewer transactions, mark
            # the current solution as the best one
            if profit > maxProfit or (profit == maxProfit and len(transactions) < len(bestTransactions)):
                maxProfit = profit
                bestTransactions = [(buyDay + 1, sellDay + 1)] + transactions
                
    # Return the best solution we found
    return maxProfit, bestTransactions

maxProfit, transactions = solve(0, 0)

print(len(transactions))
for transaction in transactions:
    print(f"{transaction[0]} {transaction[1]}")
```

Recursive algorithms like this are incredibly useful for optimization problems, and are a vital part of your problem-solving toolkit. They can be difficult to understand at first, but are absolutely worth the trouble of learning.

This algorithm returns the expected output for each of your test cases in the correct format.

Input:

```
6
1 4 2 3 3 5
```

Output:

```
2
1 2
3 6
```

Comment: Just Brilliant! It really works, however, it's really quite difficult for me to understand, considering my little experience. May I just ask some questions to you?

Comment: And am I right? if we need no more than 2 pairs of transactions, should curTransactions be equaled 2?

Comment: @LiparitG_A sure! Ask anything you'd like. I tried to add as many comments as I could to explain what was going on :)  

If you only want 2 transactions, you should change the if statement near the top where it has `if day >= N or curTransactions == 4` to `if day >= N or curTransactions == 2`

Comment: I can't get how recursion works in function body, when it is not returned. And It's not clear for me why we count profit by dividing sellday and buyday, not using delta.

Thanks :)

Comment: Still, it is not obvious for me using recursive algorithm. Do I get right, we need to write an algorithm as if it was without recursive and then apply the logic of the function to the needed place, right?

Comment: What can I read to understand recursion better?

Comment: @LiparitG_A The way the recursive algorithm works is by breaking the problem down into smaller problems that are easier to solve, then using the solutions to the small problems to solve the original problem. In this case, the if statement at the top defines the "simples" problem, which is when there are no days or no transactions left. In that case, the profit we end up with is 1, because that's the starting profit.

Comment: @LiparitG_A As for why I divided sellDay by buyDay instead of taking their difference, the reason is because profit compounds with each transaction. Instead of calculating profit gained, this function calculates the *ratio* of profit gain (buy at 1 and sell at 2 = 100% gain, buy at 2 and sell at 3 = 50%, etc). Therefore, the total ratio of gain for a transaction = the ration of gain from the transaction itself (sellDay / buyDay) * the maximum gain that can be made from transactions after the sell day. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: There's plenty of online resources for learning how to make and understand recursive algorithms, but I found [GeeksForGeeks to be pretty useful](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-recursion-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/). Another option I would *highly recommend* if you can do it is to try your hand at competitive programming (I was involved in [USACO](https://train.usaco.org/)) - I didn't rank very well in the competitions, but the training course (linked above) was really good and improved my skills greatly!